# can you permanetly store data with indexedDB while working with pouchdb

Tags: indexeddb, pouchdb

I've just started working with PouchDB it's big takeaway being the ability to store data locally in a JavaScript environment (browser) using indexedDB as well as syncing it to a CouchDB database remotely for a more permanent storage.

My question is how realistic is it to work with PouchDB to achieve permanent data storage locally with zero to little remote syncing with a CouchDB database. I'd essentially want to achieve this without having to install any services/applications locally other than the browser.

Is it safe to assume indexedDB database(s) won't get deleted? If not, what options do I have.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, IndexedDB storage is supposedly [ephemeral](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage). I.e. the browser can delete any data whenever it feels like it and be fully spec-compliant.

In practice, browsers don't seem to do this unless the user's hard drive is starting to get completely full. I've been working on PouchDB for ~2 years and I've only heard users complain once or twice about iPhone deleting WebSQL data, never about IE/Chrome/FF deleting IndexedDB data.

The browser vendors are aware that the current state of affairs is not cool, since developers can't be certain that any data they store will stick around. So there are efforts like the proposed [Quota Management API](http://www.w3.org/TR/quota-api/) to fix that.

Comment: I know, the question is a bit dated, but what about Cordova? Can I trust that the data is never wiped from the app, if Cordova + PouchDB with IndexedDB adapter is used? And if yes, is this true for both, Android 4.4+ and iOS 9+?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and FF are working on [Persistent Storage](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/#api), which is orthogonal (for now) to the Quota Management API @nlawson mentioned. The gist of Persistent Storage is you call `navigator.storage.requestPersistent()` and then your origin's web data (IndexedDB, WebSQL, etc) is safe from purging.

An early version shipped behind a flag in chrome 46, you can see it in all its limited glory at https://davidsgrogan.github.io/durable.html. (Note: https required.)